# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'object'

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am walking through [WPF Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Composite Control in WPF.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically it created an user control with Windows Form first, then adding it to a WPF application.

I have done the user control, now I am implementing the code behind file. Since it is just copy and paste code from the MSDN link, so let's look at the method.

```
private void Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        app = System.Windows.Application.Current;
        myWindow = (Window)app.MainWindow;
        myWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        wfh.TabIndex = 10;
        initFontSize = wfh.FontSize;
        initFontWeight = wfh.FontWeight;
        initFontFamily = wfh.FontFamily;
        initFontStyle = wfh.FontStyle;
        initBackBrush = (SolidColorBrush)wfh.Background;
        initForeBrush = (SolidColorBrush)wfh.Foreground;
        (wfh.Child as MyControl1).OnButtonClick += new MyControl1.MyControlEventHandler(Pane1_OnButtonClick);
        UIIsReady = true;
    }
```

There is an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'object'

At the code:

```
(wfh.Child as MyControl1).OnButtonClick += new MyControl1.MyControlEventHandler(Pane1_OnButtonClick);
```

How to correct it?

Comment: How's `MyControl1.MyControlEventHandler` defined? And what about `Pane1_OnButtonClick`? Check if the method handling the event matches the event handler definition.

Comment: Try to write it as `((MyControl1)wfh.Child).OnButtonClick += Pane1_OnButtonClick;`.

Comment: @RafaelCosta, I just copy and paste code. There is no my own code. All codes are from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr, I tried your code but unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out by myself, I have to add a dll

> System.Windows.Forms

to the WPF project, but the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) didn't mention it.